# Laravel: save,edit value from a form; undefined variable:newGoal error

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a page(admin.blade.php) that needs to display an amount. There is a button('change') present in the page, which calls upon a modal that takes an input. This modal is present inside the form whose action calls the 'change-goal' route which in turn gets the changeGoal function from the controller.

My admin.blade.php contains the form,modal and is as:

```
<a   class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moneyModal">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-money glyphicon-white"></span>change</a>  

<div class="modal fade" id="moneyModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <form method="post" action="change-goal">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Goal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please enter a new goal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control" name="newGoal" id="newGoal">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My controller is as:

```
public function changeGoal(Request $data) {
        $newGoal =DB::table('user')->whereColumn('goal')->get();
        $newGoal->updateGoal($data->goal);
        return view('admin',compact('newGoal'));
    }
```

My user model is:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'goal'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

> ```
> public function updateGoal($goal){
>         $this->goal = $goal;
>
>         $this->save();
>     }
> ```

I would like to display the value for newGoal on the admin.blade.php page. Currently I have {{ $newGoal }} written, but its giving me an error saying Undefined variable: newGoal .

I'm guessing the problem is within the controller.

> How would I be able to save the value entered in that modal/form so
>   that I can see it every time I visit the page.

Also, here's the table in case its needed:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('goal')->default(10000);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate the help.

EDIT:
My adminmanagement.blade.php (formerly admin.blade.php) is:

```
<p>Total Donations: <br> ${{ $price }}</p>
                <p>Our Goal: {{ $newGoal }}</p>

<a   class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moneyModal">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-money glyphicon-white"></span>change</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="moneyModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <form method="post" action="change-goal">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Goal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please enter a new goal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control" name="newGoal" id="newGoal">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

web.php has:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@getAllVideos')->name('/home');
 Route::post('change-goal','PagesController@changeGoal')->name('change-goal');
```

Controller:

```
 public function getAllVideos(){
        $videos = Video::all();
            $price = DB::table('donor')->sum('amount_donated');
        return view('adminmanagement',compact(['videos','price']));
    }

public function changeGoal(Request $data){

        $newGoal = $data->input('newGoal');

        auth()->user()->update([
            'goal' => $newGoal
        ]);

        return view('adminmanagement', compact('newGoal'));
    }
```

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'goal'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function updateGoal($goal){
        $this->goal = $goal;

        $this->save();
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the goal for the logged in user? Because your `DB::table('user')->whereColumn('goal')->get();` query is wrong. Your where condition does not even provide a value which would throw an error.

Comment: yes, the user is the admin here. Do I need to use the 'id' for the user instead if the 'goal' column and compare it  with the id of currently logged in user? Currently i only have one row in my database for the user table which has the field: id(auto-increment), name,email,password, and goal(i set up default value 10000). How would I be able to update the goal for logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and your code, your input field is `newGoal` and not `goal`. Your user fetching query is wrong with the `whereColumn` condition missing the value. You're complicating a simple operation.

As per your comments all you need to do is update the goal of the logged in user (admin) and return the new goal value. Do this

```
public function changeGoal(Request $request)
{
    $newGoal = $request->input('newGoal');

    auth()->user()->update([
        'goal' => $newGoal
    ]);

    return view('admin', compact('newGoal'));
}
```

**Edit** : Based your comments. You should do this to keep things simple.

```
public function getAllVideos()
{
    $videos = Video::all();
    $price = DB::table('donor')->sum('amount_donated');
    $goal = auth()->user()->goal;

    return view('adminmanagement', compact('videos', 'price', 'goal'));
}

public function changeGoal(Request $data)
{
    auth()->user()->update([
        'goal' => $data->input('newGoal')
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Change `$newGoal` to `$goal` in your view.

```
<p>Total Donations: <br> ${{ $price }}</p>
<p>Our Goal: {{ $goal }}</p>
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error, undefined variable.shall I edit my code on the question to see if I changed anything. It should be the same, mostly

Comment: I don't see you using `$newGoal` in your view anywhere. Share your complete view code.

Comment: i've added a EDIT part, the {{ $newGoal }} is present in the admin view

Comment: @AJth the issue here is you're reusing the same view for 2 routes. From your code your view already expects videos and price information. The newGold value ones comes when you update it. You need to handle this appropriately. Because the view would fail in the first controller method since it lacks newGoal. Let me update my answer to show you a good solution.

Comment: that helped. Thanks! Also, is it simple to pass this value to another view that does not need any admin. Or would that be bit complex..should I post a new question for that? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: In your code only `$goal` needs auth user. In another comment you said there's only one admin user, so you can replace `$goal = auth()->user()->goal;` with `$goal = User::first()->goal;` and the view with the data can be reused without auth.

Comment: i think it might be a bit complicated, so I created a new question, could you please have a look a it?

Comment: Could you pls check my new question here, its related to these topics you have dealt with so i thought you would have an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251865/laravel-session-pass-value-from-admin-side-to-user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

inside model

```
public function updateGoal($goal){
        $this->goal = $goal;

        $this->save();
        return $this;
    }
```

and inside your controller

```
public function changeGoal(Request $data) {
        $oldGoal =DB::table('user')->whereColumn('goal')->get();
        $newGoal = $oldGoal->updateGoal($data->goal);
        return view('admin',compact('newGoal'));
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error saying undefined variable newGoal in the admin view where I wrote {{ $newGoal }}. Any ideas?

Comment: it seems it's because of column. I got a new error saying Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "in 'where clause' (SQL: select* from 'users' where 'goal' ='').