# Laravel: (Session?) Pass value from admin side to user

Tags: php, laravel, updates

I have a value called 'goal' in admin.blade page that can be changed by the admin who is logged in. I want to be able to pass that new value on a user's page(user.blade). (There is no registered user, just a normal user accessing the page). Currently, I am able to reflect the change on the admin page, but I cannot pass the value to the user page (probably because of auth).I have tried different ways but couldn't get what i wanted. Below is the function that updates the 'goal' value when i change it:

```
public function changeGoal(Request $data){

auth()->user()->update([
            'goal' => $data->input('newGoal')

        ]);

        return redirect('/adminpage');
}
```

Using this function, when i type {{$goal}}, it  shows the changed value in the admin page(for a logged in admin.).So, right now, the admin can change the value and see the new value.

> I want the value changed by admin to show up in the user's page
>   (user.blade). How can I achieve that?

I was suggested using session, but it didn't work, or maybe I did something wrong (even though I tried to do it from the laravel documentation, couldn't really figure it out properly).
Help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach `goal` to your `User` model. Maybe you can create a `SiteData` model, which has a `goal` attribute. Then in your `user.blade.php` file you can retrieve `goal` by:

```
{{ SiteData::first()->goal }}
```

And for admin to update it:

```
SiteData::first()->update(['goal' => 1000]);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have a Try using `composer Service Provider ` to share some value / variable with `user.blade`

Comment: @Fahmi  I have three models User(meaning admin), Donor(normal users) and Videos. But, I don't have a column for the 'goal' field in the database. Or am I misinterpreting what you said? If i create a SiteData model, what should be in it?

Comment: @ReiahPaulSam I have had a look at it before, but couldn't understand how it could be implemnted for my case. It would be great if you could provide an example based on my case

Comment: sessions work only in your browser , you cannot pass such as if they are using another computer or browser. one way is to have a common table in your database to pass data.

Comment: @Demonyowh so, I create a new table, lets say 'tablegoal'. It would contain the column called goal. I guess it also needs to contain an id from the users table (admin)  and donor table(normal users) to make it a common table? How would i change my code?

Comment: yes .. exactly .. then .. in your user model you have to set a relation between them like .. Model User hasOne/hasMany Model Goal or .. if all of the normal user have one goal you dont need it .. you just have to call what goal the admin had set ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145407/discussion-between-ajth-and-demonyowh).

Comment: @sandeesh one last thing, after all this should there be two goal columns? One for the table: users and other for the table: goals?

Comment: @AJth Laravel's Eloquent is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and the idea behind it is each model corresponds to a table. For example, `User` model interacts with `users` table. So for `SiteData` model you should have a corresponding `site_data` table. Do you need to keep track of each previous goal values and the user that made the changes?